# Submit form from sibling element in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, primereact

I am trying to use a library but a submit button would be rendered outside of the form automatically (because body of the library's component is rendered as a sibling of the footer where the submit button should go). Is there a way to bind to this form so that the button that is outside of the form can trigger the form submit? Basically I want the button that is outside of the form to be able to act like it is inside the form. Is this possible?

Edit: I am using the Dialog component from the PrimeReact library. The button is in the JSX sent into the "footer" prop

[image: rendered html]

Comment: Just add a a click event listener to the button to fire `document.getElementById('theForm').submit();`

Comment: @RonnieRoyston is this possible in react? I would like to try to avoid using refs if possible

Comment: You might want to include the name of the library that you’re using, and more specifically the component.

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev added. Although I think that this is kind of a universal hack not too related to the library. I was hoping there would be a hack like when you can associate a label with an input using the `for` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button's `form` attribute allows you to set the form that the button belongs to to achieve this behavior

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="get" id="form1">
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React, you can use a ref and then dispatch an event.

The issue with using `form.submit()` or the `form` attribute is that your submit function will not be run since an event is not raised.

```js
function App() {
  const formRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('form submit fired');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef}>
        {/* form stuff here */}
      </form>
      <button onClick={() => formRef.current.dispatchEvent(
        new Event('submit', { cancelable: true, bubbles: true })
      )}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
}

form::before {
  content: 'your form here';
}
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: form attribute worked well for me, the function was run successfully